# Чтение данных из файла excel

Tags: php, javascript

Как при помощи js или php, можно прочитать файл .xlsx и занести таблицу в массив или  json, это уже не столь важно, лавное как прочитать.

Пытался подружится с PHPExcel, три примера чтения нашел в сети, но как то не вышло, не могу разобраться в чем проблема.. может есть еще варианты? Или на другом языке каком нибудь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К phpExcel есть родная инструкция с примерами.
Если занести лист в массив то смотрите в сторону toArray() 
http://w3init.com/php/libraries/convert-excel-sheet-into-php-array-using-phpexcel/

Нормальный пример

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный пример, намного лучше тех что нашел я на форумах. Все коротко и ясно, и главное работает)

Comment: Если планируете читать большие файлы используйте фильтры, они не плохо описаны в документации